# Problem with webEngine JavaFX using with swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm trying to load browser using JavaFX WebEnginge to swing as below

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> InitGUI());
```

```
final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
panel.add(jfxPanel);

Platform.runLater(() -> {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    webView.getEngine().load("https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/London");
});
```

Websites shows in my swing application but when I'm moving a mouse on the loaded website IntelliJ throws

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.sun.javafx.embed.EmbeddedSceneInterface.mouseEvent(int, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, int, int, int, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)'
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.sendMouseEventToFX(JFXPanel.java:426)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.processMouseEvent(JFXPanel.java:465)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4691)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4677)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4528)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I should add mouseEventListeners somewhere? Whole GUI is in my Main class, without any buttons, just JLabels and this webView from javaFX. Error occurs only on this webView every time I move mouse/click. Other swing components don't throw anything.

@edit
I haven't posted first line of exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.sun.javafx.embed.EmbeddedSceneInterface.mouseEvent(int, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, int, int, int, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)'
```

Comment: make sure you have all necessary modules (controls, swing, fxml, web) on both compile and runtime path. If so and still stuck, provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Unrelated: java naming conventions, please

Comment: Works fine for me. I am using Oracle's JDK 15 and JavaFX 15 from OpenJFX and Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0) on Windows 10 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved**

I've added

```
--module-path /Users/<user>/javafx-sdk-15/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing
```

in Run>Edit Configurations>VM options

Answer (score 0):

Adding the modules didn't solve it for me—I had already added them.

### A Solution

Not specifying a JavaFX version in the [JavaFX Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) solved it for me.

```
javafx {
    version = "11.0.1" // ← I removed this line
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', ...
}
```

### Details

I was trying to use [CalendarFX](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/CalendarFX); turns out the version I was trying to use, 11.8.3, uses JavaFX 13.0.1.

Once I upped or removed the JavaFX version I was including, the exception went away.

#### Full Exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.sun.javafx.embed.EmbeddedSceneInterface.mouseEvent(int, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, int, int, int, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)'
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.sendMouseEventToFX(JFXPanel.java:426)
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.processMouseEvent(JFXPanel.java:465)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4698)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4676)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4527)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am building with Maven, and my solution also had something to do with versions of dependencies, but instead of deleting the version, I upgraded every javafx library to the newest available version. Before that older versions were used which were the cause of the problem so in `pom.xml` I edited the `<version>` tags.

Before:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
```

After:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```